# Magento 2.3 - "The value of Admin scope can't be empty" error when adding new product attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

In magento 2.3 I tried to add New Product Attribute and chose Text Swatch for input type but I got the error message: "The value of Admin scope can't be empty.
" [image: Error message when adding new attribute]

Answer (score 4):

Magento 2 can be so frustrating. It's a love-hate relationship with the platform.

To solve this problem, make sure you fill, at least, both the Admin "Swatch" and "Description" fields for each Swatch option you are configuring.

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please Goto `Manage Labels` and check default value for Attribute Label is exist or not.

Also, Most of important, All options of this attribute, must have Admin Column Value. Please Open `Manage Swatch (Values of Your Attribute)` and check  Admin column has value for all options.

See Screenshot [image]

The Admin Column must a value. As per as, your screenshot, Some options do not have any admin Column value.